# Problem with cURL and rest API

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api, curl

I use last version of wordpress and woocommerce but I get this `{"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot list resources.","data":{"status":401}}` when I try to get product by curl in php. there is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://localhost/wp-json/wc/v1/products  -u ck_4e2f7166b48212888b1bb1d0a6e54371878abfd1:cs_822687fc36460c6a6d767737c967dfcfdcf2c3db");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
```

I also use `\`  before -u but still I get `Error 401`. is there any spacial option should I use for CURL in php?

Answer (score 2):

The `curl_init` function accepts an url and what you are passing there looks like a command line call.

Please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064271/how-to-use-basic-authorization-in-php-curl) for an example of passing username and password through `php curl` functionality.

Basically you have to use just *http://localhost/wp-json/wc/v1/products* in curl_init and set username using `curl_setopt` function with `CURLOPT_USERPWD` parameter.

Example:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/wp-json/wc/v1/products');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,'your credentials');
//other options here
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: It didn't work.I get that CURL from this doc [woocommerce-rest-api-docs](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs)

Comment: That example is for command line curl. Are you sure you have right permissions for the user you are trying to use?

Comment: My user is admin and i checked token

Comment: You need to authenticate the user before making any request. As suggested by WooCommerce team, you should use already implemented library for making requests.

Comment: The only thing which you need to do is to go to command line(unix) and type in this command  `composer require automattic/woocommerce` . It will install their library. Alternatively, you can go to woocommerce api docs page, **Introduction** -> **Libraries and Tools** and follow the link to download PHP library

Comment: Here is a code snippet after you downloaded their library: `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

    $wc = new Client(
        'your_wp_url',
        'consumer_key',
        'consumer_secret',
        array(
            'version' => 'v1'
        )
    );

    print_r( $wc->get( 'products' ) );`

Comment: I used it before but I couldn't get product by category. how can I do that? I'm struggling plz help

Comment: Indeed, I cannot filter either. I tried `$wc->get( 'products', array('slug'=> 'my_slug', 'per_page'=> 1, 'filter'=>['paged'=> 1, 'posts_per_page' => 1]) ))` and didn't work. It seems to be a issue with the plugin. Can you submit a support issue on the plugin support? or even on the library github page?

Comment: Finally I managed to filter for products with certain category. `$wc->get( 'products', array( 'filter' => array( 'category' => 'test' ) ) ) )`. After I had a look at their V3 api code and managed to get only products with certain category. Note that you have to use V3 api and  category slug in your filter

Comment: for more details you can browse the api code from `\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\api\legacy\v3` to see what parameters they use, especially **get_products** and **query_products** methods

Comment: As stated http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v3.html#view-list-of-products , you can only use the following filters to filter products: **type**, **category**, **tag**, **shipping_class**, **pa_* ** and **sku**

Comment: thanks a LOT, but this version is very limited.